# How to check if a matrix is close to identity matrix?

Tags: math, matrix, optimization, genetic-algorithm, rotational-matrices

I wanted to know if there exists a scalar measure of how close a rotational matrix is to an identity matrix of the same dimensions? If not can anyone please suggest a workaround?

I am doing an optimization study using genetic algorithm and rotational matrices which are close to identity matrices are more desirable. That is why I need this measure for including in the fitness function.

Answer (score 1):

A fairly simple one is

```
d(S,T) = sqrt( Trace( (S-R)'*(S-R)))
```

This is a metric in the mathematical sense, ie

```
d(S,T) >= 0, and d(S,T) = 0 iff S==T
d(S,T) = d(T,S)
d(S,T) <= d(S,U) + d(U,T)
```

moreover it is invariant under multiplication, ie

```
d( U*S, U*T) = d( S*U, S*T) = d( S, T)
```

In the above each of S,T,U are orthogonal matrices

Comment: Please fix the formula at the top and add a notion (and probably a link) to Frobenius distance you used to calculate the metric.

Answer (score 0):

In case of rotational matrix (not homogenuous one) if the matrix is identity then:

1. abs value of each row and column is `1.0`
2. dot between any two rows is `0.0`
3. dot between any two columns is `0.0`
4. no two rows are equal
5. no two columns are equal

So simply check all rows or columns with some threshold. For "close to" You could construct a score. For example something like this:

```cpp
m[n][m]; // your n x m matrix
score=0.0; // score
for (i=0;i<n;i++) // abs value of rows
  {
  a=0.0;
  for (j=0;j<m;j++ ) a += m[i][j]*m[i][j];
  score+=abs(1.0-sqrt(a))/n;
  }
for (i=0;i<n;i++) // dot between rows
 for (j=i+1;j<n;j++)
  {
  a=0.0;
  for (k=0;k<m;k++ ) a += m[i][k]*m[j][k];
  score+=abs(a)/(n*n);
  }
```

Now `score` should hold some value. the closer it is to zero the more close to identity the matrix is. the bigger the value the less close to identity it is. So:

```
if (score<threshold) matrix_is_identity;
```

where threshold is some small value like `1e-3` dependent on what you consider to still be "close to" identity. I constructed the example score so it should be invariant on matrix size. You can add weights between size and dot products or add own tests ... The first part of score sense how far your basis vectors are from unit size and the second part sense the perpendicularity of your basis vectors.

In some cases is better to `max` out instead of `+=` the score like:

```
score = max(score,a);
```

instead of:

```
score+= a/n;
```

or:

```
score+= a/(n*n);
```

depends on the behavior you want ...